# Create an array from an object of objects

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to create an useable array that I can loop through.

Starting JSON looks like this:

```
"body": {
        "count": 116,
        "value": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "workItemId": 23515,
                "rev": 1,
                "revisedBy": {
                    "id": "redacted",
                    "name": "redacted",
                    "displayName": "redacted",
                    "url": "redacted",
                    "_links": {
                        "avatar": {
                            "href": "redacted"
                        }
                    },
                    "uniqueName": "redacted",
                    "imageUrl": "redacted",
                    "descriptor": "redacted"
                },
                "revisedDate": "2023-11-30T16:32:00.577Z",
                "fields": {
                    "System.Id": {
                        "newValue": 23515
                    },
                    "System.AreaId": {
                        "newValue": 234
                    },
                    "System.NodeName": {
                        "newValue": "DevOps"
                    },
                    "System.AreaLevel1": {
                        "newValue": "Contoso"
                    },
                    "System.AreaLevel2": {
                        "newValue": "Shared Services"
                    },
                    "System.AreaLevel3": {
                        "newValue": "DevOps"
                    },
                    "System.Rev": {
                        "newValue": 1
                    },
                    "System.AuthorizedDate": {
                        "newValue": "2023-11-30T16:32:00.16Z"
                    },
                    "System.RevisedDate": {
                        "newValue": "2023-11-30T16:32:00.577Z"
                    },
                    "System.IterationId": {
                        "newValue": 203
                    },
                    "System.IterationLevel1": {
                        "newValue": "Contoso"
                    },
                    "System.IterationLevel2": {
                        "newValue": "2023Q4"
                    },
                    "System.WorkItemType": {
                        "newValue": "User Story"
                    },
                    "System.State": {
                        "newValue": "New"
                    },
                    "System.Reason": {
                        "newValue": "New"
                    },
                    "System.AssignedTo": {},
                    "System.CreatedDate": {
                        "newValue": "2023-11-30T16:32:00.16Z"
                    },
                    "System.CreatedBy": {
                        "newValue": {
                            "displayName": "redacted",
                            "url": "redacted",
                            "_links": {
                                "avatar": {
                                    "href": "redacted"
                                }
                            },
                            "id": "redacted",
                            "uniqueName": "redacted",
                            "imageUrl": "redacted",
                            "descriptor": "redacted"
                        }
                    }
                 }
              ]
          }
```

I'm attempting to create an array of 'fields' and loop through each key.

If I use the createarray() function to initialize a variable, I'm left with this:

```
            "value": [
                {
                    "System.AreaId": {
                        "oldValue": 233,
                        "newValue": 234
                    },
                    "System.AreaPath": {
                        "oldValue": "IPFS\\Shared Services\\Database",
                        "newValue": "IPFS\\Shared Services\\DevOps"
                    },
                    "System.NodeName": {
                        "oldValue": "Database",
                        "newValue": "DevOps"
                    },
                    "System.AreaLevel3": {
                        "oldValue": "Database",
                        "newValue": "DevOps"
                    },
                    "System.Rev": {
                        "oldValue": 113,
                        "newValue": 114
                    },
                    "System.AuthorizedDate": {
                        "oldValue": "2023-12-22T13:15:14.493Z",
                        "newValue": "2023-12-22T13:34:31.793Z"
                    },
                    "System.RevisedDate": {
                        "oldValue": "2023-12-22T13:34:31.793Z",
                        "newValue": "9999-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                    },
                    "System.ChangedDate": {
                        "oldValue": "2023-12-22T13:15:14.493Z",
                        "newValue": "2023-12-22T13:34:31.793Z"
                    },
                    "System.Watermark": {
                        "oldValue": 126007,
                        "newValue": 126014
                    },
                    "System.BoardLane": {
                        "newValue": "ADO Automation"
                    },
                    "WEF_292A6CA8129248189CA52399E366EBC5_System.ExtensionMarker": {
                        "oldValue": false,
                        "newValue": true
                    },
                    "WEF_B8D7CB8BBE4B44ABB66660A5EDCCB21E_System.ExtensionMarker": {
                        "oldValue": true,
                        "newValue": false
                    },
                    "WEF_C63F4704F90D431A8B59108A6997DBEE_System.ExtensionMarker": {
                        "oldValue": true,
                        "newValue": false
                    }
                }
            ]
```

This creates one single index.  What I'm after is this:

```
            "value": [
                    "System.AreaId": {
                        "oldValue": 233,
                        "newValue": 234
                    },
                    "System.AreaPath": {
                        "oldValue": "IPFS\\Shared Services\\Database",
                        "newValue": "IPFS\\Shared Services\\DevOps"
                    },
                    "System.NodeName": {
                        "oldValue": "Database",
                        "newValue": "DevOps"
                    },
                    "System.AreaLevel3": {
                        "oldValue": "Database",
                        "newValue": "DevOps"
                    },
                    "System.Rev": {
                        "oldValue": 113,
                        "newValue": 114
                    },
                    "System.AuthorizedDate": {
                        "oldValue": "2023-12-22T13:15:14.493Z",
                        "newValue": "2023-12-22T13:34:31.793Z"
                    },
                    "System.RevisedDate": {
                        "oldValue": "2023-12-22T13:34:31.793Z",
                        "newValue": "9999-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                    },
                    "System.ChangedDate": {
                        "oldValue": "2023-12-22T13:15:14.493Z",
                        "newValue": "2023-12-22T13:34:31.793Z"
                    },
                    "System.Watermark": {
                        "oldValue": 126007,
                        "newValue": 126014
                    },
                    "System.BoardLane": {
                        "newValue": "ADO Automation"
                    },
                    "WEF_292A6CA8129248189CA52399E366EBC5_System.ExtensionMarker": {
                        "oldValue": false,
                        "newValue": true
                    },
                    "WEF_B8D7CB8BBE4B44ABB66660A5EDCCB21E_System.ExtensionMarker": {
                        "oldValue": true,
                        "newValue": false
                    },
                    "WEF_C63F4704F90D431A8B59108A6997DBEE_System.ExtensionMarker": {
                        "oldValue": true,
                        "newValue": false
                    }
               ]
```

Any ideas how to make this possible?

Comment: Are you open to using a third party connector?

Comment: Yes, what are you thinking?

Comment: I’ll give you an answer and you can take it or leave it. Will get back to you soon(ish).

Comment: You last JSON code (what you are after), isn't valid JSON. It will have to be `[ {...}, {...} ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using good old string replace.

Example input:

```json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "System.AreaId": {
        "oldValue": 233,
        "newValue": 234
      },
      "System.AreaPath": {
        "oldValue": "IPFS\\Shared Services\\Database",
        "newValue": "IPFS\\Shared Services\\DevOps"
      },
      "System.NodeName": {
        "oldValue": "Database",
        "newValue": "DevOps"
      },
      "System.AreaLevel3": {
        "oldValue": "Database",
        "newValue": "DevOps"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Example output:

```json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "field": "System.AreaId",
      "oldValue": 233,
      "newValue": 234
    },
    {
      "field": "System.AreaPath",
      "oldValue": "IPFS\\Shared Services\\Database",
      "newValue": "IPFS\\Shared Services\\DevOps"
    },
    {
      "field": "System.NodeName",
      "oldValue": "Database",
      "newValue": "DevOps"
    },
    {
      "field": "System.AreaLevel3",
      "oldValue": "Database",
      "newValue": "DevOps"
    }
  ]
}
```

Power Automate expression used:

```js
json(
  replace(
  replace(
  replace(
  replace(
    string(
      outputs('Compose') // replace this with your variable/action
    ),
  '[{', '[{"field":'),
  '},', '},{"field":'),
  ':{', ','),
  '}}', '}')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you provided originally is a little different to the result when you use `createArray()` but that aside, if you want a (relatively) simple approach, you can use the `Json Properties to Name Value Pair Array` operation within   `Advanced Data Operations` connector.

The connector is quite affordable and has a great set of operations to choose from.

https://statesolutions.com.au/json-properties-to-name-value-pair-array/

https://statesolutions.com.au/pricing/

This is the resulting data set that you can then loop over and do what you need with ...

```
[
  {
    "propertyName": "System.AreaId",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "Integer",
        "propertyValue": 234
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.AreaLevel1",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "Contoso"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.AreaLevel2",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "Shared Services"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.AreaLevel3",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "DevOps"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.AssignedTo",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": []
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.AuthorizedDate",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "Date",
        "propertyValue": "2023-11-30T16:32:00.16Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.CreatedBy",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "Object",
        "propertyValue": [
          {
            "propertyName": "_links",
            "propertyType": "Object",
            "propertyValue": [
              {
                "propertyName": "avatar",
                "propertyType": "Object",
                "propertyValue": [
                  {
                    "propertyName": "href",
                    "propertyType": "String",
                    "propertyValue": "redacted"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "propertyName": "descriptor",
            "propertyType": "String",
            "propertyValue": "redacted"
          },
          {
            "propertyName": "displayName",
            "propertyType": "String",
            "propertyValue": "redacted"
          },
          {
            "propertyName": "id",
            "propertyType": "String",
            "propertyValue": "redacted"
          },
          {
            "propertyName": "imageUrl",
            "propertyType": "String",
            "propertyValue": "redacted"
          },
          {
            "propertyName": "uniqueName",
            "propertyType": "String",
            "propertyValue": "redacted"
          },
          {
            "propertyName": "url",
            "propertyType": "String",
            "propertyValue": "redacted"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.CreatedDate",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "Date",
        "propertyValue": "2023-11-30T16:32:00.16Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.Id",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "Integer",
        "propertyValue": 23515
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.IterationId",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "Integer",
        "propertyValue": 203
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.IterationLevel1",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "Contoso"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.IterationLevel2",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "2023Q4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.NodeName",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "DevOps"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.Reason",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "New"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.Rev",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "Integer",
        "propertyValue": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.RevisedDate",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "Date",
        "propertyValue": "2023-11-30T16:32:00.577Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.State",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "New"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "System.WorkItemType",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "newValue",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "User Story"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

... from there you could use a `Select` operation to further reduce each item to only the properties you want.

If you want it to be further broken down without the additional steps, you (or I could help you) can also write some C# code and use the `Execute C# Script` operation from within the same connector.